# How to solve this problem with my navbar?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this code(below) that makes a hamburger icon on mobile devices and when the user click it a wave appears and cover everything on the screen. but i have a problem that the wave can't cover the input

My question is how to make the input disappears under the wave?

This is the HTML:

```
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel=”stylesheet” href=”css/bootstrap-responsive.css”>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
 </head>
 <body>
    

   <nav id="nav-bar">
      <div class="hamburger">
        <div class="line"></div>
        <div class="line"></div>
        <div class="line"></div>
      </div>
      <h3 id="brand">BRAND</h3>
      <ul class="nav-links">
        <li class="menu"><a class="items" href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="menu"><a class="items" href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li class="menu"><a class="items" href="#">Create Account</a></li>
        <li class="menu"><a class="items" href="#">Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

<section class="s1">
   <header class="shorten">
      <div class="container">
      <div class="intro-text">
      <div class="intro-lead-in wow zoomIn" data-wow-delay="0.3s">Hello world</div>
      <div class="intro-heading wow pulse" data-wow-delay="2.0s">Hello world</div>
      <div class="row wow rotateInUpLeft" data-wow-delay="0.3s">
      <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
      <form method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" id="shorten" class="form-inline"><div style="display:none;"><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST" /><input type="hidden" name="_csrfToken" autocomplete="off"/></div>
      <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" name="url" placeholder="Your URL Here" required="required" class="form-control input-lg" id="url" />
      <input type="hidden" name="ad_type" value="2" />
      <button class="btn-captcha" id="invisibleCaptchaShort" type="submit"><img src="Right-Arrow.png" alt="" /></button></div>
      <div style="display:none;"><input type="hidden" name="_Token[fields]" autocomplete="off" /></div>
      </form>
      <div class="shorten add-link-result"></div>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      </header>
   
  /section>
```

This is the CSS code:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* THIS CSS CODE FOR THE NavBar */
#nav-bar {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: 9vh;
    background: #ffd000;
    padding-top: 1rem;
  }
  #brand{
      padding-top: 0.5rem;
      padding-left: 4rem;
      
  }
  
  .nav-links {
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    width: 35%;
    height: 100%;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: 2rem;
  }
  
  .items {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  }
  
  @media screen and (max-width: 950px) {
    .line {
      width: 30px;
      height: 3px;
      background: white;
      margin: 5px;
    }

    .nav-links{
        position: absolute;
    }
    #brand{
        padding-top: 0.5rem;
        padding-left: 0;
    }

    #nav-bar {
      position: relative;
      padding-top: 0;
    }
  
    .hamburger {
      position: absolute;
      cursor: pointer;
      right: 5%;
      top: 50%;
      transform: translate(-5%, -50%);
      z-index: 2;
    }
  
    .nav-links {
      background: #5b78c7;
      height: 94.8vh;
      width: 100%;
      margin-right: 0;
      flex-direction: column;
      clip-path: circle(100px at 100% -18%);
      -webkit-clip-path: circle(100px at 100% -18%);
      transition: all 2s ease-out;
      pointer-events: none;
    }
    .nav-links.open {
      clip-path: circle(1000px at 90% -10%);
      -webkit-clip-path: circle(1000px at 90% -10%);
      pointer-events: all;
    }
    .menu {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    .items {
      font-size: 20px;
    }
    .menu:nth-child(1) {
      transition: all 0.5s ease 0.3s;
    }
    .menu:nth-child(2) {
      transition: all 0.5s ease 0.5s;
    }
    .menu:nth-child(3) {
      transition: all 0.5s ease 0.7s;
    }
    .menu:nth-child(4) {
        transition: all 0.5s ease 0.9s;
      }
      .menu:nth-child(5) {
        transition: all 0.5s ease 1.1s;
      }
    .menu.fade {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }

/* THIS CSS CODE FOR THE FORM */

.s1 {
    height: 90vh;
    width: 100%;
    background: #ffd000;
    overflow: hidden;
}

@media (min-width: 768px){
    header .intro-text {
        padding-top: 200px;
        padding-bottom: 200px;
    }
}

header .intro-text {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 100px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px){
    header .intro-text .intro-lead-in {
        font-size: 23px;
        line-height: 23px;
        margin-bottom: 25px;
    }
}

header .intro-text .intro-lead-in {
    font-family: Montserrat,sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 27px;
    line-height: 22px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

header .intro-text .intro-heading {
    font-size: 60px;
    line-height: 60px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}



@media (min-width: 768px){
    .col-sm-offset-2 {
        margin-left: 16.66666667%;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 768px){
    .col-sm-8 {
        width: 66.66666667%;
    }
}



button, input, select, textarea {
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
    line-height: inherit;
}
input {
    line-height: normal;
}
button, input, optgroup, select, textarea {
    color: inherit;
    font: inherit;
    margin: 0;
}

.shorten #shorten .form-group {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}



@media (min-width: 768px){
    .form-inline .form-group {
        margin-bottom: 0;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
}

.form-group {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

@media (min-width: 992px){
    .shorten #shorten input.input-lg {
        width: 555px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 768px){
    .shorten #shorten input.input-lg {
        width: 470px;
    }
}

.shorten #shorten input.input-lg {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.35);
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 19px;
    height: 53px;
    padding-right: 60px;
}
@media (min-width: 768px){
    .form-inline .form-control {
        display: inline-block;
        width: auto;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 576px){
    .form-inline .form-control {
        display: inline-block;
        width: auto;
        vertical-align: middle;
        margin-left: auto;
    }
    
}


.input-lg {
    height: 46px;
    padding: 10px 16px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 1.3333333;
    border-radius: 6px;
}

.form-control {
    display: block;
    width: 60vh;
    height: 60px;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    font-size: 17px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: #555;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
    -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
    -o-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
    -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,-webkit-box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
    transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,-webkit-box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
    transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
    transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s,-webkit-box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
}

.shorten #shorten button {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 7px;
    top: 6px;
}
```

This is the JavaScript code:

```
const hamburger = document.querySelector(".hamburger");
const navLinks = document.querySelector(".nav-links");
const links = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-links li");

hamburger.addEventListener("click", () => {
  navLinks.classList.toggle("open");
  links.forEach(link => {
    link.classList.toggle("fade");
  });
});
```

Comment: Try apply a z-index property to your #nav-bar css selector see more on z-index property https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a z-index to your `.nav-links.open`

```js
const hamburger = document.querySelector(".hamburger");
const navLinks = document.querySelector(".nav-links");
const links = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-links li");

hamburger.addEventListener("click", () => {
  navLinks.classList.toggle("open");
  links.forEach(link => {
    link.classList.toggle("fade");
  });
});
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* THIS CSS CODE FOR THE NavBar */
#nav-bar {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: 9vh;
    background: #ffd000;
    padding-top: 1rem;
  }
  #brand{
      padding-top: 0.5rem;
      padding-left: 4rem;
      
  }
  
  .nav-links {
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    width: 35%;
    height: 100%;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: 2rem;
  }
  
  .items {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  }
  
  @media screen and (max-width: 950px) {
    .line {
      width: 30px;
      height: 3px;
      background: white;
      margin: 5px;
    }

    .nav-links{
        position: absolute;
    }
    #brand{
        padding-top: 0.5rem;
        padding-left: 0;
    }

    #nav-bar {
      position: relative;
      padding-top: 0;
    }
  
    .hamburger {
      position: absolute;
      cursor: pointer;
      right: 5%;
      top: 50%;
      transform: translate(-5%, -50%);
      z-index: 2;
    }
  
    .nav-links {
      background: #5b78c7;
      height: 94.8vh;
      width: 100%;
      margin-right: 0;
      flex-direction: column;
      clip-path: circle(100px at 100% -18%);
      -webkit-clip-path: circle(100px at 100% -18%);
      transition: all 2s ease-out;
      pointer-events: none;
    }
    .nav-links.open {
z-index:99;
      clip-path: circle(1000px at 90% -10%);
      -webkit-clip-path: circle(1000px at 90% -10%);
      pointer-events: all;
    }
    .menu {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    .items {
      font-size: 20px;
    }
    .menu:nth-child(1) {
      transition: all 0.5s ease 0.3s;
    }
    .menu:nth-child(2) {
      transition: all 0.5s ease 0.5s;
    }
    .menu:nth-child(3) {
      transition: all 0.5s ease 0.7s;
    }
    .menu:nth-child(4) {
        transition: all 0.5s ease 0.9s;
      }
      .menu:nth-child(5) {
        transition: all 0.5s ease 1.1s;
      }
    .menu.fade {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }

/* THIS CSS CODE FOR THE FORM */

.s1 {
    height: 90vh;
    width: 100%;
    background: #ffd000;
    overflow: hidden;
}

@media (min-width: 768px){
    header .intro-text {
        padding-top: 200px;
        padding-bottom: 200px;
    }
}

header .intro-text {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 100px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px){
    header .intro-text .intro-lead-in {
        font-size: 23px;
        line-height: 23px;
        margin-bottom: 25px;
    }
}

header .intro-text .intro-lead-in {
    font-family: Montserrat,sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 27px;
    line-height: 22px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

header .intro-text .intro-heading {
    font-size: 60px;
    line-height: 60px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}



@media (min-width: 768px){
    .col-sm-offset-2 {
        margin-left: 16.66666667%;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 768px){
    .col-sm-8 {
        width: 66.66666667%;
    }
}



button, input, select, textarea {
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
    line-height: inherit;
}
input {
    line-height: normal;
}
button, input, optgroup, select, textarea {
    color: inherit;
    font: inherit;
    margin: 0;
}

.shorten #shorten .form-group {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}



@media (min-width: 768px){
    .form-inline .form-group {
        margin-bottom: 0;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
}

.form-group {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

@media (min-width: 992px){
    .shorten #shorten input.input-lg {
        width: 555px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 768px){
    .shorten #shorten input.input-lg {
        width: 470px;
    }
}

.shorten #shorten input.input-lg {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.35);
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 19px;
    height: 53px;
    padding-right: 60px;
}
@media (min-width: 768px){
    .form-inline .form-control {
        display: inline-block;
        width: auto;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 576px){
    .form-inline .form-control {
        display: inline-block;
        width: auto;
        vertical-align: middle;
        margin-left: auto;
    }
    
}


.input-lg {
    height: 46px;
    padding: 10px 16px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 1.3333333;
    border-radius: 6px;
}

.form-control {
    display: block;
    width: 60vh;
    height: 60px;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    font-size: 17px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: #555;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
    -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
    -o-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
    -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,-webkit-box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
    transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,-webkit-box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
    transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
    transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s,-webkit-box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
}

.shorten #shorten button {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 7px;
    top: 6px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">


<nav id="nav-bar">
  <div class="hamburger">
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div class="line"></div>
  </div>
  <h3 id="brand">BRAND</h3>
  <ul class="nav-links">
    <li class="menu"><a class="items" href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="menu"><a class="items" href="#">Contact</a></li>
    <li class="menu"><a class="items" href="#">Create Account</a></li>
    <li class="menu"><a class="items" href="#">Login</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<section class="s1">
  <header class="shorten">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="intro-text">
        <div class="intro-lead-in wow zoomIn" data-wow-delay="0.3s">Hello world</div>
        <div class="intro-heading wow pulse" data-wow-delay="2.0s">Hello world</div>
        <div class="row wow rotateInUpLeft" data-wow-delay="0.3s">
          <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
            <form method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" id="shorten" class="form-inline">
              <div style="display:none;"><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST" /><input type="hidden" name="_csrfToken" autocomplete="off" /></div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="url" placeholder="Your URL Here" required="required" class="form-control input-lg" id="url" />
                <input type="hidden" name="ad_type" value="2" />
                <button class="btn-captcha" id="invisibleCaptchaShort" type="submit"><img src="Right-Arrow.png" alt="" /></button></div>
              <div style="display:none;"><input type="hidden" name="_Token[fields]" autocomplete="off" /></div>
            </form>
            <div class="shorten add-link-result"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>

</section>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cf3uz5xm/

Comment: That sovles the problem but the hamburger icon also disappears so the user can not click again to make the wave get back... Anyway i got a helpful answer and it solved the problem

Answer (score 2):

You should only add a "z-index: 1" style into ".nav-links.open"

Edit your CSS like below:

```css
.nav-links.open {
    clip-path: circle(1000px at 90% -10%);
    -webkit-clip-path: circle(1000px at 90% -10%);
    pointer-events: all;
    z-index: 1;  //Add this line
}
```

Comment: It did not work, when i write (z-index : -1;) the input disappears

Comment: Oh sorry you should add (z-index: 1) to (.nav-links.open). I eddited my answer.